# Passenger preloader error with nginx and apache

Tags: nginx, passenger, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a rails 2 application which I want to run on Apache or Nginx, but for both of them I am getting the same error:

[image: Error facing for both Apache and nginx]

nginx.conf

```
     passenger_root /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini;
     passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs

    server {
            listen 80;
            server_name web.test.com;
            root /home/vishal/workspace/website/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
    }
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

The app is running fine with passenger standalone, but causing issues with nginx and apache.

I tried to understand the supporting doc but could not find the solution. I want to use nginx for the app.

Comment: It looks like you app is using the wrong Ruby. It looks like you're expecting your app to be run under Ruby 1.8 (the one installed by RVM), but it's actually being run in Ruby 1.9. Which Ruby interpreter do you intend to run your app as?

Comment: I want ruby 1.8 interpreter, how can i do it ? Do I need to reinstall passenger and nginx?

Comment: You need to use the [passenger_ruby](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby) config option. The documentation teaches you how to set this option properly when using RVM.

Comment: Great. :) I've submitted a proper answer, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the issue was that you're running your app under the wrong Ruby. You intended it to be run under RVM Ruby 1.8, but it was actually being run under Ruby 1.9 thanks to the "passenger_ruby /usr/bin/ruby" option that you see there.

You need to use the [passenger_ruby](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#PassengerRuby) config option to tell Passenger to use RVM Ruby 1.8. The documentation teaches you how to set this option properly when using RVM.